# From graph to .dot file python

Tags: python, decision-tree

I have a tree represented by this string (this is a decision tree made by scratch):
**{'index': 1, 'right': {'index': 0, 'right': 'no', 'value': 'overcast', 'left': 'Yes'}, 'value': 'Mild', 'left': {'index': 0, 'right': {'index': 0, 'right': 'Yes', 'value': 'overcast', 'left': 'Yes'}, 'value': 'rain', 'left': {'index': 0, 'right': 'Yes', 'value': 'rain', 'left': 'Yes'}}}**

and I'd like to represent it (with edges and nodes using Graphviz). 
To print it I use this function in Python:

```
def print_tree(node, depth=0):
    filename = outlook.csv'
    dataset = load_csv(filename)
    columns = dataset[0]
    if isinstance(node, dict):

        print('%s[%s = %s]' % ((depth * ' ', (columns[node['index']]), node['value'])))
        print_tree(node['left'], depth+1)
        print_tree(node['right'], depth+1)
    else:
        print('%s[%s]' % ((depth*' ', node)))
```

I'd like to use Digraph from GraphViz
from graphviz import Digraph

```
 def createGraph(node):
 dot = Digraph(comment="experiment")
 def graph(node):
  if isinstance(node, dict):
    dot.node(str(id(node)))
    dot.edge(str(id(node)) , str(id(node['right'])))
    graph(node['left'])
    graph(node['right'])
  else:
    dot.node(str(id(node)), str(node))
  dot.render('test-output/roundround5.gv', view=True)
 'test-output/round.gv.pdf'
graph(node)
```

but obviously code is wrong. Can anybody help?

Comment: You are creating a brand-new `Digraph()` object for each node in your graph.  You need to do that, and the rendering at the end, *outside* of your recursive function, so that it only happens once.  Also, you may have some issues due to using the `id()` of nodes as your Graphviz node names.  That will work for your interior nodes, but for the leaf nodes that are simply a string, it is undefined whether or not all of those `'Yes'` nodes (for example) will have the same id.

Comment: Here's an example of creating a dot file from a binary tree - actually, it's a treap, so a mashup of a binary tree and a binary heap: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/treap/trunk/m4_treap.m4 .  Feel free to raid it for ideas. BTW, the extension is ".m4", but that's just a preprocessor so that I could generate pure python and cython from the same file.  To get the .py, just run m4 -Dpy=1 < ../m4_treap.m4 > py_treap.py

Comment: Why is your code "obviously wrong"? It is missing from your post so you might want to [edit] and add it.

Comment: @jasonharper you're right. I edited my code but I have always problems.

Comment: If you tell us what those problems are, we might be able to help more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some syntax errors in your code blocks, the filename `outlook.csv` is not quoted correctly, and there's an extra string `'test-output/round.gv.pdf'` on the end of the graphing block.

The main problem though seems to be that you are building a new `Digraph` object for every call to `graph()`, and you are calling graph recursively. Instead you need to make one `Digraph`, and pass that into the first call to `graph`, and then recursively add the graph nodes.

Can you expand your question a bit - address the syntax errors and then provide an example of an errors or incorrect output you are seeing?